# What will be the value of $h'(1)?$

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.Define $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by,
$$h(x)=\int_0^x\int_0^xf(u,v)dudv$$
What will be the value of $h'(1)?$

I am getting no clue about this problem.I tried but don't know how to approach.

Comment: Agree, there is no $x$ on the right hand side. $h(x)$ is constant, or you made a typo.

Comment: I am extremely sorry.I have edited the question.

Comment: Definitely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304937/derivative-of-double-integral-with-respect-to-upper-limits (call $u=y, v=z$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $h(x)$ be given by the integral

$$h(x)=\int_0^x \int_0^x f(u,v)\,du\,dv$$

Then, using [Leibniz's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement) for differentiating under the integral sign, the deriviative $h'(x)$ is given by

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{h'(x)=\int_0^x f(u,x)\,du+\int_0^x f(x,v)\,dv} \tag 1$$

To see this perhaps a bit more easily, we let $F(x,v)\equiv \int_0^x f(u,v)\,du$.  Then, we can write

$$h(x)=\int_0^x F(x,v)\,dv$$

Now, using Leibniz's Rule, we see that

$$h'(x)=F(x,x)+\int_0^x \frac{\partial F(x,v)}{\partial x}\,dv \tag 2$$

Using $F(x,x)=\int_0^x f(u,x)\,du$ and $\frac{\partial F(x,v)}{\partial x}=f(x,v)$ in $(2)$ reveals that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{h'(x)=\int_0^x f(u,x)\,du+\int_0^x f(x,v)\,dv}$$

which agrees with the result in $(1)$.