# Question about referenced question: "Derivative of double integral with respect to upper limits"

Tags: integration, derivatives

I did not get the first step of the derivation in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304937/derivative-of-double-integral-with-respect-to-upper-limitsmits)

The correct is:
\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} dy \left[\int_{0}^{x} f(y,z)\, dz \right]
&=\int_{0}^{x} f(x,z) \,dz + \int_{0}^{x} dy\, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_{0}^{x} f(y,z)\, dz \right].
\end{align}

But, for me it should be (using the derivative product rule):

\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} dy \left[\int_{0}^{x} f(y,z)\, dz \right] &=\frac{d}{dx} \left(\int_{0}^{x} dy \right)\int_{0}^{x} f(y,z)\, dz + \int_{0}^{x} dy \,\frac{d}{dx} \left(\int_{0}^{x} f(y,z)\, dz \right)\\ &=\int_{0}^{x} f(y,z)\, dz + \int_{0}^{x} dy\, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_{0}^{x} f(y,z)\, dz \right].
\end{align}

So I am putting a $y$ in place of an $x$.

Could you please detail this first step and explain why I am wrong?

Comment: The integrals here are not being multiplied (notice the dependence of $f$ on $y$). Try substituting $F(x,y) = \int_0^x f(y,z)\, dz$ and applying Leibniz rule.

Comment: ok. Got that the integrals are not being multiplied but how can I use $F(x,y) = \int_0^x f(y,z)\, dz$ ? Could you detail please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $F(x,y) = \int_0^x f(y,z) dz$. Then we want to evaluate $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xF(x,y) dy.$$ By Leibniz rule, 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xF(x,y) dy &= F(x,x) + \int_0^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,y)dy \\
&=  \int_0^xf(x,z)dz + \int_0^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_{0}^{x} f(y,z)\, dz \right] dy
\end{align}
which is what was found in the other post.